# OpenGTS Enterprise - Piccolo Device Configuration

Tags: opengts

I have set up OpenGTS environment and can able to access front page of OpenGTS.

Now how can i receive data from my Piccolo device ? How to configure it with Open GTS ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to configure your device to send data to the IP address of your server with your port number (find a free port number on your system). Once you do this, then you'll either have to write a DCS for your device, or get one from the Geotelematic. If you already have this set up, then on your DCS configuration file, you'll have to set the port number you set up on your device and then start up your DCS. Make sure you add that port to any firewalls on your system so that the packets from the device aren't blocked. You should be able to see packets coming in, at least on your logs. If there isn't make sure the DCS is running using the bin/psjava command.